# ship http endpoints of a spring-boot app to elasticsearch

Tags: java, spring-boot, elasticsearch, metrics, metricbeat

I'm following this article   https://aboullaite.me/spring-boot-elastic-kibana/to configure my spring-boot app to send its metrics to elasticsearch using **HTTPBeat**, although the app is running successfully the index in elaticsearch had not been created! and there is no connection established between the app and es!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should start the httpbeat app, accroding to httpbeat.yml, the app is used to get your spring boot application health and metrics and output to elasticsearch

1. download and install the httpbeat  app from https://github.com/christiangalsterer/httpbeat/releases
2. run it with the following command

   ./httpbeat -c httpbeat.yml
3. start your spring boot application and then you can see the data in the elasticsearch

Comment: I'm stuck in the httpbeat installation o n my windows machine  , I  posted  a  question , thus   have  u any idea to help [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52339853/httpbeat-installation-on-windows-8-1-issue)

Comment: why not download the pre-compiled windows binaries? https://github.com/christiangalsterer/httpbeat/releases/download/4.1.0/httpbeat-4.1.0-windows-x86_64.zip