# HTTPBeat installation on windows 8.1 issue

Tags: http, spring-boot, elastic-stack, metrics, endpoint

I'm trying to pump a spring-boot app metrics to elasticsearch using Httpbeat ,I'm following  this  https://aboullaite.me/spring-boot-elastic-kibana/ ,I'm struggling  to install httpbeat into my windows machine I installed Go ,but I'm stuck  at the  glide installation, is  there  any alternative that I can use rather than HTTPbeat ,And  if you know a  clear method  rather  than the  official documentation please help me, I  have a  demo the next Monday and  I'm fully stuck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try docker install for httpbeat. Go to https://github.com/evanhoucke/httpbeat for more info. Use the docker image evanhoucke/httpbeat.

Comment: Thanks  for  your response, I already used  the precompilation version of httpbeat for  windows  users ,And  it's  running correctly